# Jobs, search on a tag as such - also perhaps a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Having fun browsing through the "jobs" site I noticed two things ..

this morning, go to jobs and search on "iOS"

(FWIW I searched by "Newest" and "any location".)

(A)

It would be really desirable to find only items that have "iOS" **as an actual tag** for the job.

About 19 in 20 (quick actual estimate) "mention" iOS in the text in some way ("additionally helpful! you know what iOS is! you once owned an iOS phone!" and so on)

So the search results are (usually) largely useless

How to search on "tags" in jobs product?

(B)

I believe there may be some outright **bugs or near-bugs** in the search

For example, these blokes don't even incidentally mention iOS: [no iOS here!](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/89662/senior-frontend-developer-friendsurance) but it appears in the results if you simply search on "ios".

It's admirable that (perhaps as an option) you can additionally search on "ios incidentally mentioned anywhere" but I, for one, have only ever used it meaning "search on actual iOS jobs".

(Thought)

Surely one should be able to simply **select tags to search on**, rather as on SO?  (Indeed, would't it "know" my favorite tags from SO, such as C64, Lisa etc?

## But wait ....

it turns out that if you

## tag:something

it will actually search for the tags.

This can't be desirable - a case in a system where the "expected commonplace behavior has become obscuritan".  Can it be changed?

[image]

(Aside - I believe on SO as such, when you search on "ios" it in fact searches on the tag, or at least emphasizes that search?)

Comment: I agree with the fact that it should be possible to search by just tags and that the results shouldn't include jobs that don't have anything to do with iOS. But at the same time it looks like there are also quite a few companies looking for an actual iOS developer without having added the [tag:ios] tag to the SO job page, which means that you would miss these if you purely restricted yourself to searching by tags.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a keyword we search a variety of fields on the job, including tags. This acts as a filter, but under the hood it will actually give jobs with the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag a higher score than those that don't have the tag. Why do we do this? Because employers are notoriously bad at using tags correctly. Stack Overflow users (and moderators) tend to be much better at this so we can rely upon the data much more heavily.

However, you're using newest sort which disregards any scoring information. So you're getting all jobs with ios in their body, title, tags, etc. sorted by the date they were posted.

Currently our matches sort also disregards that data but we have an upcoming experiment that starts to factor it into the algorithm. Once that goes live (we hope - it's an experiment after all) matches sort will have a much better view of these kinds of searches.

**Edit:** *The aforementioned experiment was successful, and the default "matches" sort now displays at the top of the list the job offers which best match the entered keyword(s). Note that your Stack Overflow question view history and your match preferences also affect the order of search results.*

However, you can use the filter UI by pressing the 'filters' button:

[image: Filters]

And then enter tags that you're interested in to filter by tags directly.

[image: Tag search]

As you've noticed you can also use [advanced search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs) to filter by tag directly.

Also, the job you mentioned doesn't contain `ios` in the publically facing data but the employer has actually targeted Android, iOS and java web development in their targeting profile:

[image: Targeting profile]

Comment: Hi Dean, interesting - it's tricky to satisfy every need right?  Your tip of basically "not using newest" seems pertinent.  Just for me, I'd make it that "newest" works exactly using your other cool algorithm you described, but just then sort by newest.  Cheers!