# Job alerts are a bit inaccurate

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have created a `Swift` tag job alert for myself.

And then in my email I received the following alert:

[image]

Which has no `Swift` tag.

I looked into the [job description](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/141229/google-software-engineer-android-google) and found that it had a single mention of Swift while it was actually an Android job.

So is there anyway that job descriptions could be made more accurate and strictly based on the **tag**, or its pros outweigh it's cons and it's just something that we have to deal with?

Comment: Does https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346084/871146 help?

Comment: @DeanWard the question is more written like a story and hard to get to the bottom of it :(. Though your answer seems to address the reason why there is such a drawback, but doesn't it seem buggy? That all I want to know. Because this job alert is no way a job for Swift. It's purely a small bonus to have...and usually when you arrive at these jobs they never touch the other OS